# allocating memory in c, freeing in c++

Tags: c, visual-c++

**UtilityTest.cpp** and **utility.c** are in two different project but in a single solution.

In UtilityTest.cpp, after calling **'BytesToString(pbArray,5)**', it fails to **free**. Why?

We cannot allocate memory in c and free in c++?

> UtilityTest.cpp

```
[Owner("SHRI")]
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Automatic")]
[Description("Convert byte to string")]
void ConvertByteToString()
{
    unsigned char pbArray[5] = { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45 };
    char* pbExpArray = NULL;
    unsigned int Flag = 1;
    int len = 0;

    pbExpArray = BytesToString(pbArray,5);
    len=strlen(pbExpArray);
    Flag=strcmp("41 42 43 44 45 ",pbExpArray);
    free(pbExpArray);
}
```

> utility.c

```
char* BytesToString( const unsigned char* PpcbBytes, const unsigned int PuiNoOfBytes)
{
    unsigned char bRetVal = 0;
    char tempStr[5];
    unsigned int ctr = 0;
    char* PpszString = NULL;

    do
    {
        PpszString=(char*)calloc(PuiNoOfBytes*3+1,sizeof(char));
        if(NULL==PpszString)
            break;
            for(;ctr<PuiNoOfBytes; ctr++)
            {
                    sprintf(tempStr, "%02X ", PpcbBytes[ctr]);
                    strcat(PpszString, tempStr);
            }
    } while(0);
    return PpszString;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it fails to free?

Comment: Do you create a .dll or a static library of the one of those projects ? And how do you know it fails to free ? (any error messages you can show us ? )

Comment: An exception of type 'System.AccwssViolationException' occurs.

Comment: Error message : An exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Common_Test.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Is this really the full code? The BytesToString function seems completely redundant, all it does is this: `PpszString = calloc(PuiNoOfBytes*3+1,sizeof(char));` The rest of that function is useless fluff.

Comment: Also please ask yourself why the module allocating the memory isn't the same one that frees it. The program design doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I did not show some lines because even if I add it or comment(remove) it, I get the same error. I will add it if you want

Comment: I have shown full code now. Please go through.

Comment: That code works fine, assuming that both translation units are linked to the same RTL. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I'm still wondering if one of these projects are a dll, in which case you can't allocate in the dll and free it outside the dll. Or that one project statically links in the RTL and the other does not, etc.

Comment: My Test project(Common_Test) which contains UtilityTest project runs with the CLR support. Is that the reason?

Comment: It looks like it should work, although there are obscure things in the code. For example, you never null terminated PpszString before calling strcat(), but out of luck you get away with it only because calloc() guarantees that all bytes are set to zero. Had you used malloc() instead of calloc(), this code would crash and burn. Consider adding the line `PpszString[0]='\0'` directly after the check against NULL, or at the very least make a comment about calloc creating the null termination for you.